# Julia transpose vector of vectors

Tags: multidimensional-array, julia, transpose

I have a vector of vectors, say

```
julia> m=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
3-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 2]
 [3, 4]
 [5, 6]
```

which I want to transpose, meaning that I want a 2-element vector with the corresponding 3-element vectors (1,3,5 and 2,4,6).

This could obviously be done with loops, but I suspect that this is slow and am sure that Julia has a better solution for it. The best one I could come up with so far looks like that:

```
julia> matrixM=reshape(collect(Iterators.flatten(m)), (size(m[1],1),size(m,1)))
2×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  3  5
 2  4  6

julia> map(i->matrixM[i,:], 1:size(matrixM,1))
2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 3, 5]
 [2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: Loops are fast in Julia. If you need optimal performance, loops are nearly always the answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
julia> using SplitApplyCombine

julia> invert([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 3, 5]
 [2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: This does exactly what I want, but also only uses for loops. I find it hard to believe that there's no better solution performance wise; if no-one comes up with one though, I'll believe you.

Comment: What kind of possible solution would not boil down to just using loops at some level?

Answer (score 0):

If the inner vector has only two entries, one can use this:

```
m = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
[first.(m), last.(m)]
```

Output:

```
2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 3, 5]
 [2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score -1):

A `zip` approach ala Python

```
m = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
[zip(m...)...]
```

Output:

```
2-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64}}:
 (1, 3, 5)
 (2, 4, 6)
```

However, it appears slow for 100 elements, and  for 1000 elements my jupyter-lab kernel even restarts.
(One more reason to stay with Python.)

Comment: Of course it's slow. You are creating tuples of length 1000, and the compiler must specialize code for that, which overwhelms it. Tuples are for small collections, and splatting works best for statically known lengths. You find a heavily suboptimal solution, then complain it's the language's fault?

Comment: The problem isn't with `zip`, but with splat. Splatting dynamically sized containers, and creating dynamically sized, and _huge_, tuples, will be slow, and this is well-known. My downvote goes to your answer. Not mainly because of the solution itself, but because of the petulant quip.